# Download File from another php script

Tags: php, file, download

Hello guys i have a problem: downloading a file from another php file.
In a page that I have create there are a lot of dropdown lists, when i select an option it must download a specific file. Everything is working perfect in my localhost, but when i upload the same files to a server, the files that i download are renamed as downloadFile.php, i have tried calling downloadFile.php from links(a tag), from jquery, from ajax call but they all rename the file.
last I used:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cboLinks" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option name="selectFormat" value="">Select a format</option>
    <option name "Text" value="downloadFile.php?userID='.$row['id'].'&format=txt">Text</option>
    <option name="HTML" value="downloadFile.php?userID='.$row['id'].'&format=html">HTML</option>
</select>
```

Locally it works but on server it doesn't, what is the reason that it happens does anyone know?

**EDIT:**
BTW this is the code that i download the file from downloadFile.php

```
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($user.$format));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($user.$format));
        readfile($user.$format);
```

Comment: Some links: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920372/download-a-renamed-file-with-php) - [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212225/download-and-rename-file-from-server-using-php-script) - [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801076/renaming-files-when-downloading-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return correct `headers` in your `downloadFile.php`

call `header` before `readfile` in your `downloadFile.php`

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your_file.name"');
// then only call
readfile($file);
```

there are also many other headers which you can use check here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: dude you saved me :D i had to edit the part you wrote, forgot to add double quotes in filename attirbute :D and now it works :D